# Cannot connect to vsftpd on Azure virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, azure, ftp, virtual-machine

I have virtual machine on Windows Azure (Ubuntu).

I have installed vsftp on server and assigned end points in Azure portal for FTP.

But when I try to connect with FileZilla, it's giving me below error:

> Command:   PWD
>   Response:  257 "/"
>   Command:   TYPE I
>   Response:  200 Switching to Binary mode.
>   Command:   PASV
>   Response:  227 Entering Passive Mode (100,66,218,25,240,15).
>   Command:   LIST
>   Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
>   Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing

Here is snapshot of Azure endpoints:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used `SFTP` connection. I have `SSH` in azure endpoints.

Simply use your `ssh` username and password to login in filezilla.

Host: your server IP address

Protocol: SFTP: SSH File Transfer Protocol

User: SSH username

Password: SSH password

Comment: Did you do any setting configuration on ubuntu's end? just the above credentials on filezilla?have tried but failed.

Comment: It shows Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity and
Error: Could not connect to server

Comment: @davidlee: You need to set endpoint in azure portal. port: 22 for SSH.

Answer (score 0):

The FTP server is listening on the port 61455 for data transfer connection:

> Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (100,66,218,25,**240,15**).

`240 << 8 + 15 = 61455`

You do not have that port allowed in the end points configuration.

You have to allow all the ports in your FTP server data connection port range in the end points configuration.

If you need to allow large range of ports, you can use the `Add-AzureEndpoint` PowerShell cmdlet.

See my guide on [Azure endpoint provisioning](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_azure_ftps_server#firewall).

Answer (score 0):

try using WinSCP

[image: click advanced]

then under the conection menu, uncheck passive mode,
[image: uncheck passive mode]